# Which files do I need to release with my program that uses ODBC?

Tags: c++, database, odbc

I remember when i was studying up ODBC and learning the api and stuff, I seen someone talk about

> you need to release some files with your program etc, etc.

So I was wondering if anyone here who uses ODBC knows which files I need to include with my program for it to correctly connect to my DB from a different computer. Thanks I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

This [note from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/123008) support explains which files you need to provide.  The files are not sufficient by themselves, as you also need to set up and configure ODBC.  This is explained as well.  And if you use something other than oracle and sqlserver you have to look in addition for the appropriate ODBC driver.

Instead of ODBC, you could consider [ADO.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27y4ybxw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is part of the .Net framework and which can as well connect to an ODBC source.  The [installation process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is straightforward, and self-containing distribution package can be downloaded form Microsoft